# If else structure not setting correct url in android app?

Tags: java, android

The if else structure is not setting correct url even though location and category parameters
are correctly parsed i have checked it using log messages.

```
private void initView(String location,String category) {
// show progress dialog
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
String url;
if(location.toString()=="Jaipur" && category.toString()=="Gardner")
url = "http://192.168.186.1/apps_jaipur_gardner.php";
else if(location.toString()=="Jaipur" && category.toString()=="Mason")
url = "http://192.168.186.1/apps_jaipur_mason.php";
else if(location.toString()=="Jaipur" && category.toString()=="Carpenter")
url = "http://192.168.186.1/apps_jaipur_carpenter.php";
else if(location.toString()=="Jaipur" && category.toString()=="Plumber")
url = "http://192.168.186.1/apps_jaipur_plumber.php";
else
url = "http://hello.hostei.com/appsonline.php";
Log.d(TAG,location);
Log.d(TAG,category);
Log.d(TAG,url);
FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
task.execute(url);
}
```

Comment: Dupe of "How do i compare strings on java"

Comment: Unrelated, but please indent your code properly.

Comment: `.equals("whatever")` instead of `=="whatever"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a very big mistake! Strings are *reference types*, when you use == to compare two reference types, you are comparing the location in memory of those two strings but not whether they have the same characters. This is a mistake that many beginners will make so don't worry, you are not alone.

Instead, you should use the `equals` method in the `String` class. That method compares what we all want - the characters!

You should do something like:

```
if (location.equals("Jaipur") && category.equals("Gardener"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try **.equals** instead of **==**
May be this can help you